# Class object inside program block in system verilog

Tags: class, verilog, system-verilog

Can we create a class object inside the program block in sv?
I want to create a transaction class handle inside my test written in the program block.

```
class MyClass; 
  // Class definition here
endclass

program MyProgram;
  initial begin
    MyClass myObj; // Instantiate an object of MyClass

    // Use the class object within the program block
    myObj = new;
    myObj.someMethod(); // Call a method of MyClass

    // Perform other operations with myObj

  end
endprogram
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `program` block can refer to things outside its scope just like a `module`. The reverse is not true—you cannot refer to anything declared in a `program` block from outside of it. But there is nothing preventing you from constructing a class object in a program block and using its handle outside the program block as long as the class is declared outside the program block. The *reactive region* scheduling semantics of procedural code gets determined by process created by the `initial` block, not where the code is declared.

I strongly recommend ***against*** the use of program blocks and use a module instead. See https://blogs.sw.siemens.com/verificationhorizons/2009/05/07/programblocks/

Answer (score 0):

This table is helpful for answering the post:    [what-goes-where-in-systemverilog](https://www.amiq.com/consulting/2014/10/01/what-goes-where-in-systemverilog/)

The table indicates that a class within a program block is allowed in SystemVerilog.

[image]